# macrabbit's CSSEdit not recognizing selector

Tags: macos, css

I'm styling an submit type input and noticing that CSSEdit isn't applying the styles in its preview.  The CSS validates and works in Safari & FF.

```
input[type="submit"] {
    height:27px;
}
```

Anyone else have this problem with CSSEdit?

Comment: How about sending an email to the vendor's support? Go to *Help » Send Feedback*.

Comment: Email sent and no reply. This developer has tardy or no replies to support q's.  That's why I'm on this site, Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue, although the behavior in CSSEdit and Safari was the same.

Reason: It seems Safari ignores `height` for buttons whose other properties are unchanged in order to be able to draw the native Aqua styled button. Add `border: 1px;` to that definition -- in that case, both height and other properties of the button changed for me.